# How to ask someone "Will you marry me"

Tags: vocabulary

So, not to look to far ahead. (Okay, not to look to far ahead at all). I'm interested in how to say" Will You marry me" I've read "你愿意嫁给我吗？“    “和我结婚，好吗” and “嫁给我好吗？“ Is there a clear "best" way to say this?

Comment: you should say "嫁给我吧"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All can be the best way under their particular circumstances.

你愿意嫁给我吗？ Very formal, ritualistic.

和我结婚，好吗？ 嫁给我好吗？ Bookish. People write that in letters.

嫁给我算了 This is what guys (who think they are not up to the standards) say to their long-time girl friends who are still waiting for Mr. Perfect. It's like saying, "I'm not perfect, but don't let prudence ruin the best things in life."

Comment: 嫁给我算了 sounds very informal and it should not be used unless the couple got used to these style of talking. (Some girls like it formally happened while some might not...)

Comment: That's what guys say to their classmates in the summer before they graduate.

Comment: So they say that to flirt/play around?

Comment: @PeteC. You are right. Be careful using this phrase. It is for older people whose are done with film scripts and sentimental scenes. It's the kind of thing Bror Blixen say to  Karen Dinesen.

Comment: The explanation of `嫁给我算了` is a little misleading. "I'm not perfect, but don't let prudence ruin the best things in life." sounds not bad, even, a little romantic in English, but, `嫁给我算了` implies "you see, (I bet) you can't find a better one than me." Unless the listener would potentially accept such wording, it's not a good idea to say that.

Comment: 算了 to resign to something less. But the tone is very informal.

Answer (score 2):

嫁 means "to marry a man". So "你愿意嫁给我吗？"only works if it's the guy who's doing the proposing. If it's the woman proposing, she would say, "你愿意娶我嗎？"

It's a modern world, you know. Can't assume it's always the guy who proposes. Anyways, I hope this will provide a different perspective and possibly some ladies out there might find it useful. Having said that, “和我结婚，好吗?” is probably easier as it works both ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you made an romantic proposal, then ask for 嫁给我好不好？ This is same for 你愿意嫁给我吗.
If you are too familiar with each other, and want to do flatly, just say 我们结婚吧.

Answer (score 0):

你愿意嫁给我吗？is the way normally we will say when the man ask the loved one to marry him.
also we will say ,和我结婚，好吗” and “嫁给我好吗？it is also ok.
you can see this article to check more about Common Chinese Nicknames for Your Loved Ones
http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/article/daily-chinese-learning-tips/chinese-nicknames-for-your-loved-ones/